# TCP both Client and Server on the same PC

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, connection, client

I'm trying to implement a small tcp based application in C#. I'm new to TCP programming.

The app is really simple. It's a client/server scenario, which support max 2 clients. One client will be an "external" IP, the other will be the host itself.

Everytime a client connect to the server, it begins to receive and send packets from/to the server.

I have set up a small console app which implements both TCP server side code and TCP client code.

The server use a listener binded to a specific port and wait for client connections. Once a client is connected, it spawn a new thread to handle communication with the client.

The client simply connect to the server and once the connection is estabilished it starts to receive and send pakcets.

As I said before "the host is also client of itself", but this leads to an issue. If the client send a packet to the server, both server and client claims to have received a packet. It is normal? Am I missing something?

UPDATE 2 (fixing issue)

I think I've found the issue. I need to "reset" the buffer once the send operation is done by the client

```
          case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:                        

              // Put in listen mode

              // Buffer reset AFTER send and BEFORE receive
              _receiver.SetBuffer(new byte[4096], 0, 4096);

              _client.ReceiveAsync(_receiver);                        

              break;
```

UPDATE 1 (adding code)

**Server**

```
    public void Host()
    {                        
        _listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.ConnectionPort));
        _listener.Start();

        this.IsListening = true;            

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Blocks until a client connections occours
                // If continue with no client then stop listening                    
                try
                {
                    TcpClient client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    // Add client to peer list
                    long assignedID = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
                    _clients.Add(assignedID, client);

                    HandleClient(assignedID);

                    if (this.ConnectedClients == this.MaxClients)
                    {
                        _listener.Stop();

                        this.IsListening = false;

                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Server has stop listening
                    _stopListen.Set();

                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void HandleClient(long assignedID)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
        {
            long clientID = (long)state;
            TcpClient client = _clients[clientID];        

            try
            {
                byte[] message = new byte[4096];
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                int readed = 0;
                int index = 0;

                NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

                while (true)
                {                        
                    readed = clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                    if (readed == 0)
                    {
                        // Client disconnected, thorw exception
                        throw new SocketException();
                    }

                    Array.Copy(message, 0, buffer, index, readed);
                    index += readed;

                    if (readed == 4096
                        && !_packetHub.IsValidBufferData(buffer))
                    {
                        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        readed = 0;
                        index = 0;

                        continue;
                    }

                    if (_packetHub.IsValidBufferData(buffer))
                    {
                        NetPacket receivedPacket = _packetHub.DeserializePacket(buffer);
                        NetPacket answerPacket = null;

                        // Assign sender ID in case of unknown sender ID
                        if (receivedPacket.SenderID == NetPacket.UnknownID)
                            receivedPacket.SenderID = clientID;

                        // Handle received packet and forward answer packet
                        // to the client or to all other connected peers                            
                        answerPacket = HandlePacket(receivedPacket);                            
                        if (answerPacket != null)
                        {                                
                            if (answerPacket.RecipientID == clientID)
                            {
                                // Send answer packet to the client
                                SendPacket(client, answerPacket);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Broadcast packet to all clients
                                foreach (TcpClient peer in _clients.Values)
                                    SendPacket(peer, answerPacket);
                            }
                        }

                        // Reset receive packet buffer
                        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        readed = 0;
                        index = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Network error occours!");
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close client connection
                client.Close();

                // Remove the client from the list
                _clients.Remove(clientID);

                // Raise client disconnected event
                OnClientDisconnected();
            }

        }, assignedID);
    }
```

**Client**

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        if (this.ConnectionAddress == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to connect. No server IP specified.");

        _receiver = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        _receiver.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(this.ConnectionAddress, this.ConnectionPort);
        _receiver.SetBuffer(new byte[4096], 0, 4096);
        _receiver.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Socket_OperationComplete);

        _client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);            

        _client.ConnectAsync(_receiver);
    }

    private void Socket_OperationComplete(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)            
        {
            switch (e.LastOperation)
            {
                case SocketAsyncOperation.Connect:

                    _readyToSend = true;

                    this.IsConnected = true;

                    // Once connection is estabilished, send a join packet to
                    // retrive server side assigned informations

                    JoinPacket joinPacket = (JoinPacket)NetPacket.CreatePacket(this.ClientID, NetPacket.ToHost, NetPacket.JoinPacket);
                    joinPacket.ClientName = this.ClientName;
                    joinPacket.ClientAddress = this.LocalAddress.ToString();

                    SendPacket(joinPacket);

                    break;

                case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:

                    _readyToSend = true;

                    byte[] buffer = _receiver.Buffer;

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Client received packet (" + _packetHub.GetBufferDataType(buffer) + ") with length of: " + buffer.Length);

                    if (_packetHub.IsValidBufferData(buffer))
                    {
                        NetPacket receivedPacket = _packetHub.DeserializePacket(buffer);
                        NetPacket answerPacket = null;

                        // Handle received packet and forward answer packet
                        // to the server
                        answerPacket = HandlePacket(receivedPacket);
                        if (answerPacket != null)
                            SendPacket(answerPacket);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _client.ReceiveAsync(_receiver);
                    }

                    break;

                case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:                        

                    // Put in listen mode
                    _client.ReceiveAsync(_receiver);                        

                    break;
            }
        }            
        else
        {
            OnClientDisconnected();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Network error: {0}", e.SocketError.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide us with any code?

Comment: How does the client "claim" to have received a package?

Comment: Does the server and the client share port?

Comment: Yeah you are right, udpated with code

Comment: So, what is precisley your error ?

Comment: Once the client is connected (SocketAsyncOperation.Connect in the Socket_OperationComplete event) it sends to the server a JoinPacket. Either the server and the client (which are the same app instance) will receive the packet. In the receive event of the client (SocketAsyncOperation.Receive in the Socket_OperationComplete event)  the buffer contains also the data sent by the client.

Comment: Which port / ip adress are you using?

Comment: I think I've discovered the issue, I need to "reset" the buffer once the Send operation is done. What I was reading is the packed sended by the server mixed up with the last sent by the client. See my last update

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using TCP, you have to specify a port to send/listen (different for server and client). So no, it isn't normal (but it is if client and server are sending/listening on the same port).

Comment: The server start listening on a certain port. When a connection is estabilished, I suppose it assign a new socket with a new port. Is it right? 

The client tries to connect to the server using the same port used by the listener. Once the connection is estabilished it should use different port to send and receive? Do I have to specify where to listen?

Comment: With your implementation, it seems to be right this way. I was thinking that you were using to different sockets. I'll take a look at this.